# Which is the best graph chart plugins for web application?

Tags: javascript, php, graphs, charts, json

We are looking for chart library (open source) for implementation. It came too many from that we choose CHART.JS & GOOGLE CHART for the development. Please help us to know which is better? In all aspects, mainly in coding and we found Google Chart more easy to code and implement. Please give some thoughts in this topic. If there any other plugins which is more effective besides these two please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential Charts](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-charts) for JavaScript is an option to consider. 30+ Chart types available.

The whole product is available for free through the community license if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Through the above link they are offering free trial and also listed the pricing for three varients not mentioned anything about community license.Is there any link to know more about it ? @Arun

Comment: You can refer this https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/)!
We have a very large selection of 2D and 3D charts which are hardware accelerated through WebGL if real-time performance is needed! You can have professional, elegant, and well-designed charts set up and running in hardly a few minutes with the user-friendly API.

There is also a free community edition you can use. For more information about that check this [link](https://www.arction.com/community-license/).

Have a look at the [Interactive Examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) to see if something in there catches your eye.

Disclosure: I am a dev for LightningChart!

Comment: Welcome Daniel!  Although it's obvious that you are somehow affiliated with LightningChart (which is no problem, as long as your community involvement extends beyond promoting your own products), please do add a formal disclosure to your post to indicate the nature of your affiliation.  Thanks, and welcome!